# If one field in row is entered, all the other fields in the row are required

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is a code to enter date, select  in/out and location.
If the user want more fields to enter i also added a addRow function.

```
<table>    
for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){ 
<tr><td>
<input type='datepick' name='scheduledatepick[$i]' />
<select name='schedulein[$i]' /><option>--</option>
<input type='text' name='location[$i]' />
</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

Now my question is if a user entered a field in a row(maybe datepick or schedulein or location) then he must enter all the other fields in that same row. How to achieve this?
 [image]

Comment: Looks like a question to me...

Comment: @Town he re-edited it to include a question just now.

Comment: @Chaitu Thank you for re-editing the post to include a question.

Comment: Can we focus on the question, please.

Comment: @Chaitu sure, now that there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this to happen on a <kbd>button</kbd> click, you can do this:  **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/aEcXu/)**

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // set up an array to store the invalid rows
    var rows = new Array();
    $('table tr')
        // reset all rows before we validate
        .removeClass("error")
        // loop over each row
        .each(function(i) {
            // work out whether the fields are completed or not
            var filledFieldCount = 0;
            filledFieldCount += $("[name='scheduledatepick[" + i + "]']", this).val().length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            filledFieldCount += $("[name='schedulein[" + i + "]']", this).val() !== "--" ? 1 : 0;
            filledFieldCount += $("[name='location[" + i + "]']", this).val().length > 0 ? 1 : 0;

            // if the total completed fields for this row
            // is greater than none and less than all
            // then add the row to the invalid rows list
            if (filledFieldCount > 0 && filledFieldCount < 3) {
                rows.push(this);
            }
         });

    // finally, change the background of the
    // rows to mark them as invalid
    if (rows.length > 0){
        $(rows).addClass("error");
    }

});
```

**CSS**

```
.error { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: excellent. this is the one i`m looking for. had to make some slight modifications to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/3xDAx/

Answer (score 1):

PHP-side:

```
$errs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    $cnt = empty($_REQUEST['scheduledatepick'][$i]) + empty($_REQUEST['schedulein'][$i]) + empty($_REQUEST['location'][$i]);
    if ($cnt > 0) && ($cnt != 3) {
        $errs[] = "Row $i not completed";
    }
}
if (count($errs) > 0) {
   ... at least one incomplete row
}
```

Javascript-side would be somewhat equivalent, with extra code to handle differences between selections, checkbox, text fields, textareas, etc...

Comment: Surely that'd just check for _any_ empty fields, rather than empty fields on a row with at least one field populated?

Comment: Looks like it should! I'll +1 it and assume, on the back of your massive reputation, that it works ;)

Comment: @Marc B, thanks for the answer, but I`m looking for something on the client-side. Moreover this will check if there`s any empty fields not to row specific ( there can be a complete empty 2nd row)

Comment: @Chaitu: that's what the `($cnt > 0) && ($cnt != 3)`. It looks for any rows that have at least one filled in field (`$cnt > 0`), but don't have all fields filled in `($cnt != 3)`.

Comment: @Town: big numbers don't mean much. I have good days/bad days as anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the form.
If a line is incomplete, throw an error message to the user.
All this in Javascript.

Then you have to implement the same check in PHP. The Javascript check is convenient to give an immediate response to the user, but it can be easily neutralized.